# Stop anchor from rising to top

Tags: javascript

I have a frustratingly simple problem that I can't solve. I could link to 15 different stackoverflow questions that answer the same thing. I have reviewed the answers, yet I still can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work in my own situation. See the following shortened code:

Javascript:

```
function menu(link) {

if (link == "link1") {
location.href = "http://example.com/index.php?menu=referrals";
}
else if (link == "link2") {
location.href = "http://example.com/index.php?menu=internet";
}
else if (link == "link3") {
location.href = "http://example.com/index.php?menu=phone";
}

}
```

index.php:

```
<a href="#void" id="link1" onclick="menu(this.id);">
<div class="<?php echo $menubox1; ?>" id="<?php echo $box1; ?>">
<div class="title">Referrals</div>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#void" id="link2" onclick="menu(this.id);">
<div class="<?php echo $menubox2; ?>" id="<?php echo $box2; ?>">
<div class="title">Internet</div>
</div>
</a>
<a href="#void" id="link3" onclick="menu(this.id);">
<div class="<?php echo $menubox3; ?>" id="<?php echo $box3; ?>">
<div class="title">Phone</div>
</div>
</a>

<div class="frame2">
Link Content, height is a tall fixed height.
</div>
```

The location.href code works just fine. However, the page jumps to the top, seemingly ignoring the return false. All the answers I've reviewed on here make me think my code should work just fine. What am I missing here? Much appreciated.

**EDIT: I've updated the code based on given answers thus far.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `href="#"` to `href="#void"` and prevent jumping or better, don't use `a` element if you don't need it, if it does not lead anywhere. Using `href="javascript:void(0);"` is also a bad solution since that script doesn't do anything. Use `span`, `label`... and as have been said below, remove `return false`.

---

I analyzed the site and there's is nothing unexpected. Let me explain it in more details...

When you click on this link `<a href="#void" id="link1" onclick="menu(this.id);">` the `#void` part is really preventing jumping but at the same time you're leaving the current page calling this line `location.href = "?menu=referrals"` located within `menu()` function.

`?menu=referrals` and `"?menu=internet"` are totally different pages/links and that's why the browser 'jumps' at the top after loading a new page/link

To be sure on this, modify the script a bit, as following

```
function menu(link) {
    return false;   
    if (link == "link1") {
    // ...
}
```

then, scroll the page down for about 50px and click on your menu links. As you can see, the page is not jumping and you're not leaving the current page/link. In other words, you're facing just a normal browser behavior.

Finally, at this point I don't see any reason for not using a proper links; hence, this `<a href="#void" id="link1" onclick="menu(this.id);">Referrals</a>` could be written like this `<a href="/referrals">Referrals</a>` and your menu could be managed using only CSS.

Comment: So I've tried these out. Both javascript:void(0) and #void. Since you said the latter case was preferable, when I do this the URL briefly appends at #void at the end, then loads the new page and it jumps to the top of the page again. I've fixed the height of the frame (a div that contains all the content that varies with the link, and it sits below the menu code) div so that it doesn't change to make sure that wasn't it (it changes height based on the link in my original code). Still trying to think through a solution for this one, and am confused why it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @user1935137 Cuold you share the link please, (you may delete it immediately) 'cause using `href="#void"` or `href="javascript:void(0);"` should prevent jumping. This is something I'm using for ten years :) so I believe there's something else causing the issue. You may use `href="#self"` as well, anything not being used as a fragment within HTML page.

Comment: I program and design by hobby, and until now I haven't had a reason to learn Ajax. Now I have one. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` is never reached, as you are loading a new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"` to be sure the page doesn't get back to top.